# Adaptec 7901 and RAID 10 Degraded

Tags: raid, ibm

I have an IBM xSeries 226 with an Adaptec HostRAID 7902 SCSI adapter. I have 4 73GB drives setup in a RAID 10 array. Everytime I reboot the system now the RAID utility shows the array as degraded and lists drives on ID 1 and 2 to be degraded. The drives do a disk verify and pass the test just fine. I have also tried different drives in the system. Does anyone know if there is a known issue with RAID 10 and this adapter? Or maybe I can't do this and I need to figure something else out.

Comment: Make a backup, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the controller rebuild the array.  If it doesn't work, remove the disks from the array, reinitialise them and add them back to the array.  As always, make sure that you back up any data first.

Comment: Actually now that I have run the verify a couple of times I am now getting a command failure of 02h - Check Condition under the Target Status and SCSI Controller Status of - 00h - No SCSI controller error. Does this sound like something is wrong with the SCSI controller itself or does this give us any other ideas about the problem?

Comment: Check the connection and termination on the cable.  If necessary, get its FRU number and get another one off IBM or ebay.  Bonus points if you can replicate the error with another drive.  In this case it is almost certainly the controller, cable or terminator.  Otherwise, the drive could be dodgy.